# document.getElementsByName() returning null in Edge but working IE

Tags: javascript

From what I understand document.GetElementsByName is supported in Edge...

The following code is working for me in IE but not in Edge:

```
document.getElementsByName(row2.uniqueID)[0].style.backgroundColor = normalColour
```

This code gives me an error stating "Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference".

Any pointers as to why this is occurring would be much appreciated

Comment: Educated guess - `console.log(row2.uniqueID);` in both browsers and you'll see a different.

Comment: Not sure if relevant here, but MDN says: *The getElementsByName method works differently in different browsers.*

Comment: You need to provide a working sample so that we can trace what the problem is (i.e. what the html looks like, what the input to document.getElementsByName looks like, etc...)

Comment: Right, MDN says: _In IE < 10, getElementsByName() method will also return elements that have an id attribute with the specified value._, so you probably just want `getElementById`. And your code likely doesn't work in other major browsers either.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `document.getElementsByName` method the wrong way. This is supposed to be used with the `name` attribute (normally used in form inputs), but it looks like you're using it with the `id`.

Even though this works in IE, it's not a standard and it may not work in other browsers.